# Google file picker from Dart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, angular-dart

I have learned how to use the Google drive API from Dart. I can't find any documentation on using the Google file picker from Dart.

Any suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not find any better way than using dart:js interop and use google jsclient api. I tried to extract some code I have here: https://github.com/alextekartik/google-jsapi-picker.dart

Comment: It works well. How would I enhance it to allow picking folders using the setSelectFolderEnabled(boolean) feature?

Comment: I added support for it:

Comment: It is much appreciated. I admit my weakness with javascript, but efforts such as yours makes working with Dart considerably easier. Thanks man.